# How to limit Gradle downloads to only one file per instance

Tags: android, gradle

While I have an unstable connection I would like `gradle` to download files only one after another, instead of the default parallel download mode, a preview of parallel-mode is below:

[image]

Because as it is currently none of the files gets ever downloaded to its end, it's wasting time, and time is money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer the solution shared by sterling here

And we can set the `org.gradle.parallel` property in a `gradle.properties` file (which should be placed in the projects root directory, besides of `build.gradle` file), just append a line like `org.gradle.parallel=false` to `gradle.properties` file.

see also: [Disabling parralel threads](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/disabling-parallel-for-certain-tasks-only/10151)

Comment: disabling parallel threads does not guarantee disabling parallel downloads. still have 3 parallel downloads retrying on slow connection.

Comment: Disabling parallel threads in Gradle does not guarantee disabling parallel downloads. This is because Gradle downloads dependencies using a separate thread pool than the thread pool used for tasks.

To disable parallel downloads, you need to set the `org.gradle.parallel.downloads` property to false